# Recommended C++ Database Abstraction Layers

Tags: c++, database

What Database Abstraction Layer libraries would you recommend for use with C++? I am more interested in solutions for non-Windows platforms, but that is personal preference. Which libraries would you recommend and why?

Comment: [A very similar SO thread.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205802/best-portable-way-to-connect-to-sql-server-using-c)

Comment: @luke The linked page does not exist

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at [SOCI](http://soci.sourceforge.net/)

Apparently, it is a serious candidate for Boost.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I like the [database template library](http://dtemplatelib.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using an [ODBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odbc) library.

Here are the first two when I googled:

[libodbc++](http://libodbcxx.sourceforge.net/)

[sqlapi++](http://www.sqlapi.com/)