# Writing C++ for the Web

Tags: c++, web-services

Is it possible to create a C++ application that can be run trough the browser? Is there any way to link C++ application with a database (that can be used by both Mac, Linux and Windows).

Comment: What do you mean by linking a C++ application with a database? I mean, of course, you can easily use C++ to access various databases.

Comment: Do you mean run the C++ code in the browser (in which case see http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/) or write a web service for the server running in C++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's perfectly possible to do it, back in the day (when there was no PHP around), many web applications were written in C++. There is a standard called [CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) that facilitates communication between your application and your web server. This [tutorial](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/cgi.html) shows hot to set it up for an Apache web server, using Perl as the target language. You should be able to write a C++ program that prints out the same text and test it.

Databases can be accessed using C++ using a variety of libraries, depending on your needs and database system.

While all of this is totally possible, I'd be interested why you would do such a thing in the days of sophisticated frameworks and languages that are far more suited to web applications than C++. I'd certainly not recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean by "run through the browser" to run native code in the browser the only way I know of to execute native code in the browser is Google's [NaCl](https://developers.google.com/native-client/).

For server side C++ no special rules apply and it's very common. All normal rules for C++ application (including databases and linking) apply here.

Answer (score 2):

If by "through the browser" you mean a webapp, yes - you can write CGI applications in C++, as in most other languages. See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316200/which-c-library-for-cgi-programming).

[wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/) is a toolkit that may make it easier for you if you come from a desktop background.

About the portable database layer, take a look at these [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296205/recommended-c-database-abstraction-layers) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205802/best-portable-way-to-connect-to-sql-server-using-c). If all you need is *a* database that works across platforms, but don't need to be able to switch database engines across platforms, [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html) may be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

CGI or FastCGI for server side C++.

NaCl for client side C++.

Database connections with things like MySql Connector.

Answer (score 1):

Any scripting langauge can run COM. You can create COM objects in C++ that you can invoke serverside from php.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to create a C++ application that can be run trough the browser?

I'm not sure what you mean by "run through the browser" (or, for that matter, "C++ application").  pmr has already mentioned Google NaCl as one option.  If "C++ application" includes C++ plugins, then "sure, you can."  [You can compile C++ to Javascript](http://You%20can%20even%20compile%20C++%20to%20Javascript).  If you're talking about web sites or web services, I can say "yes, it's possible; I maintain a web service that uses C++ for the backend, and Amazon was once written in C++, do you have any particular question?"

It's possible to write a lot of things in a Turing complete language.  That doesn't mean it's a good idea.

> Is there any way to link C++ application with a database (that can be used by both Mac, Linux and Windows).

Again, I'm not sure what you mean by "link ... with a database."  You certainly can interact with a database using things like ODBC, [DTL](http://dtemplatelib.sourceforge.net/), LDAP or MongoDB.  You also can embed a database in your program, using things like SQLite, MySQL embedded, Firebird embedded, Berkeley DB, LevelDB, or whatever Microsoft's calling Microsoft Jet these days.  Do you have a particular question?